# How can I make HTML number field up and down arrow work on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

The increment and decrement button doesn't work.

```
<input type="number" min="0" value="0">
```

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't support <input type="number">

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="movie">How often you watch movie in week : </label><input id="movie" type="number" value="0"/>
```

http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-number.php